# Why is there a speed difference in defining a JavaScript object literal with or without quotations marks?

Tags: javascript, performance

In pure JavaScript, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) and the [Google JavaScript style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Array_and_Object_literals) suggest that the two snippets below are equivalent:

```
// Snippet one
var myObject = {
  "test":"test"
}

// Snippet two
var myObject = {
  test:"test"
}
```

I've written a test function which uses `performance.now()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29)) to measure the time it takes to create a million simple objects:

```
function test(iterations) {
  var withQuotes = [];
  var withoutQuotes = [];

  function testQuotes() {
      var objects = [];
      var startTime, endTime, elapsedTimeWithQuotes, elapsedTimeWithoutQuotes;

      // With quotes
      startTime = window.performance.now();

      for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
          objects[objects.length] = {
              "test": "test"
          };
      }

      endTime = window.performance.now();
      elapsedTimeWithQuotes = endTime - startTime;

      // reset
      objects = undefined;
      startTime = undefined;
      endTime = undefined;
      objects = [];

      // Without quotes
      startTime = window.performance.now();

      for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
          objects[objects.length] = {
              test: "test"
          };
      }

      endTime = window.performance.now();
      elapsedTimeWithoutQuotes = endTime - startTime;

      return {
          withQuotes: elapsedTimeWithQuotes,
          withoutQuotes: elapsedTimeWithoutQuotes
      };
    }

  for (var y = 0; y < iterations; y++) {
      var result = testQuotes();
      withQuotes[withQuotes.length] = result.withQuotes;
      withoutQuotes[withoutQuotes.length] = result.withoutQuotes;

      console.log("Iteration ", y);
      console.log("With quotes: ", result.withQuotes);
      console.log("Without quotes: ", result.withoutQuotes);
  }

  console.log("\n\n==========================\n\n");
  console.log("With quotes average: ", (eval(withQuotes.join("+")) / withQuotes.length));
  console.log("Without quotes average: ", (eval(withoutQuotes.join("+")) / withoutQuotes.length));
}

test(300);
```

The results I get imply that it is (marginally) faster to use quotation marks.  Why would this be?

On my browser, I get these results from my test function, (average over 300 iterations):

**With quotes**:  167.6750966666926ms
**Without quotes**:  187.5536800000494ms

Of course, it's more than possible that my test function is duff too...

**My browser:** Chrome 29.0.1547.65

Comment: You know, 20 milliseconds is about the time it takes for an AC mains line to switch the direction of its current (in 50Hz circuits). It's shorter than the time it takes for a video to cycle a frame. Are you really bothered by that difference? Were it some piece of server side code, I'd understand. But client side, if that amount of time is relevant, you're making something relly interesting there.

Comment: @Renan - it's the not knowing _why_ that bothers me!

Comment: Oh. I see. Well, it could be a number of things, and I can only speculate on those. Javascript engines have each a different implementation, so maybe it's a quirk from Chrome. Try that in Firefox and IE as well (and Opera, if you're into using that too).

Comment: I would take a guess that when parsed those keys are translated into strings by the parser and so, as strings are already strings there is no parse step present but when they're not strings the parser takes the time to generate one in it's place (this is pure speculation). I would continue the test to see if string access of properties is faster than standard dot notation (i.e. is `test["test"]` faster than `test.test`).

Comment: Try to exchange the two snippets and measure again. Maybe your CPU only needs some time to warm up :-) Also, garbage collection (and allocation place for the `objects` array) could make a difference.

Comment: [Try it here at jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/quoted-properties-in-object-literal)

Comment: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-property-string-vs-not) shows an almost immeasurable difference in the opposite direction.

Comment: I agree with *izuriel*'s theory. Maybe the compiler has to convert the key to a string before continuing. As *Renan* said, different engines will perform differently, but the theory makes sense.  I performed a rewritten test myself and found that the latter *(without quotes)* was faster by 2-4%. I urge that you perform these tests separately, one script only testing the former, and one script only testing the latter, not both in a row.

Comment: @JoeSimmons: That's a job the *parser* does, and only once. The AST should be exactly the same.

Comment: @Bergi Yea, you're right I don't know I didn't catch that. That pretty much invalidates my theory.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends from your browser.
The perfomance is approximately equivalent.
http://jsperf.com/objectquotes